# python - How to iterate string/arrays

Tags: python, arrays, string, loops

I have a question. How can I make python script like:

```
i1 -> hello
i2 -> hi
i3 -> hurra

for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    print(text)
```

My desired output:

```
hello
hi
hurra
```

So I would like to iterate "links" in function but I want actual "linked values/strings" to iterate in "output". Maybe arrays can be used? Hope I'm clear.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you calling "i1 ->"? It's not a valid syntax. Is it getting a user input? Making a list of text (need "")? else?

Comment: I also have the feeling that what you are trying to do could be implemented in a better way.. What is the context of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python doesn't have arrays like in C++ or Java. Instead you can use a list.

```
my_list = ['hello','hi','hurra']

for text in my_list:
    print(text)
```

There are multiple ways to iterate the list, e.g.:

```
for i, text in enumerate(my_list):
    print(i, text)

for i in range(0, len(my_list)):
    print(my_list[i])
```

You could use it like "arrays", but there are many build-in functions that you would find very useful. This is a basic and essential data structure in Python. Most of books or tutorials would cover this topic in the first few chapters.

P.S.: The codes are for Python 3.

Comment: Python's `list` is the actual counterpart to "arrays" of C++ or Java. And technically, Python does not have an array data type, but it has an [array module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html).

Comment: awesome, worked! this second one even on python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionaries for this purpose.

```
mydict={'i1':'hello','i2':'hi','i3':'hurra'}
for i, (key, value) in enumerate(mydict.items()):
    print("index: {}, key: {}, value: {}".format(i, key, value))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ['hello', 'hi', 'hurra']

for item in x:
    print(x)

#> hello
#> hi
#> hurra
```